# How to completely uninstall U1 client from OS X

Tags: mac, client

I recently installed the U1 client for Mac (OS X 10.8.2). It's definitely got some rough edges, like occasionally taking forever to sync and the menubar helper doesn't quit when I select Quit. So I want to remove it completely. How do I do that?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it helped me uninstall Ubuntu One. However, I still get the program com.ubuntu.one.fsevents running on startup of my Mac running Mavericks. I have to run the terminal program above to stop it every time I start up my computer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would love to have the opportunity to solve your problems with it - if you contact support at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ we will investigate.

In particular the menubar helper not quitting is a bug that I'd personally like to hear more about - if you have the time, a bug report that describes in more detail what you did and what the context was, and includes the log files from ~/Library/Caches/ubuntuone/ (those will contain file names, so you can mark it as private), would be really helpful - the place to file that bug would be here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-control-panel/+filebug

---

If you would still rather completely remove the Mac client, here's how:

First quit the service (not just the control panel app) using the quit menu item in the menubar helper.
(If that doesn't work, force quit everything with 'ubuntuone' in its name using Activity Monitor).

If you never run the app again, the ~/Ubuntu One/ folder is just another folder and nothing will change it.

You could stop here in case you would like to try using it again in the future.

To continue and really wipe everything:

1. Drag Ubuntu One.app to the trash.
2. Remove the following data and log folders:

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/ubuntuone/syncdaemon
   ~/Library/Application Support/ubuntuone/shares (NOTE: this deletes shared folders, copy any files you want to keep out first.)
   ~/Library/Caches/ubuntuone
   ~/Library/Caches/sso
   ```
3. Remove the background fsevents monitor, which watches for changes in the file system:
   from the terminal, type `sudo launchctl remove com.ubuntu.one.fsevents`
   This will prompt you for your administrator password.
   (The fsevents monitor does nothing if the syncdaemon process is not running, so this is not strictly necessary).

Comment: Thank you very much @MikeMcCracken. I submitted a bug report.