# uninstalled Ubuntu One but still seeing `com.ubuntu.one.fsevents`

Tags: ubuntu-one, services

There is a previous post on how to uninstall Ubuntu One from a  Mac and I have done all of what is required.  However, I still get the program com.ubuntu.one.fsevents running on startup of my Mac running Mavericks. I have to run the terminal program to stop it every time I start up my computer now.

Here is the link to the uninstall process;
[How to completely uninstall U1 client from OS X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232984/how-to-completely-uninstall-u1-client-from-os-x/443568#443568)

Please help.  This daemon program won't stop unless I force it to stop in terminal every time I boot up my Mac.  And now you all are discontinuing UbuntuOne so I want to make sure this is resolved quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your HD in your Mac and choose the Library folder and go to the subfolder LaunchDaemons. There you can delete the offending file.